# Creating copy of binary file from hex representation of it

Tags: c, binary, hex

I'd like to make copy of my binary file, but I need to make it from hex representation of my binary file.

In the first program I create txt file with with hex representation of my binary file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int BYTE = 1;
int counter = 0;
int read;
long size;
FILE *file1 = NULL; 
FILE *file2 = NULL; 
fpos_t length;

int main() {

        unsigned char hex[3];
        unsigned char buffer[1];
        file1 = fopen("server.pdf", "rb");
        fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_END);
        fgetpos(file1, &length);
        size = length.__pos;
        fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_SET);
        if (file1) {
                file2 = fopen("test.txt", "w");
                while (counter < size) {
                        read = fread(buffer, 1, BYTE, file1);
                        counter += read;
                        i = 0;
                        while(i<read) {
                        sprintf(hex, "%02x", (unsigned int) buffer[i++]);
                        fwrite(hex, 1, BYTE, file2);
                        }
                }
        } else
        printf("ERROR");
        fclose(file1);
        fclose(file2);


}
```

In the second, I read data from txt file and after that I write it to binary file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *file1;
FILE *file2;
int size;
fpos_t length;
int main(){
        file1 = fopen("test.txt", "r");
        fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_END);
        fgetpos(file1, &length);
        size = length.__pos;
        fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_SET);
        char buffer[1];
        char hex[3];
        int counter = 0;
        int read;
        if(file1){
                file2 = fopen("test.pdf", "wb");
                while (counter < size) {
                read = fread(hex, 1, 3, file1);
                counter += read;
                sscanf(hex, "%02x", buffer);
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 1, file2);
                }
        }
        fclose(file1);
        fclose(file2);
}
```

Unfortunately I can't open my copy. What is the reason?

Comment: Never ever read of size 1, this is slow and dumb. You have a buffer, fill it and loop through its contents.  
`read = fread(buffer, 1, BYTE, file1);` 
`count += read;`  
`i = 0;`
`while (i < read)`  
`{ sprintf(hex, "%02x", (unsigned int) buffer[i++]); fwrite(hex, 1, BYTE, file2) }`

Comment: Also, how does this compile `char buffer[size];` ?? This is forbidden by C ANSI, what kind of C is this ? Why don't you use malloc ?

Comment: I'm sorry I am not advanced in C. I do not have problems with compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the files content? You wont be able to sprintf the hex representation to the variable `hex` since it's 1 byte in size.

The variable hex is declared `hex[BYTE]` where BYTE = 1, but your sprintf format string looks like this: `"%02x"` ie 2 bytes, then you need room for a terminating zero.

The same goes for when you write to the file, you only write 1 byte from your hex string.

Declaring a variable as: `var[1]` is pointless you can achieve the same thing with `var` btw.

Besides this you should also add proper error handling, if you can not successfully open the file. This means checking the file pointer after your call to fopen, then take an appropriate action. perror() will print an error string that corresponds to errno, and in case of a file that does not exist it will print something like: "no such file or directory" or similar.

Comment: Could you explain me it in more detailed way?

Comment: Changing to "%01x" didn't help

Comment: You are not suppose to change the format string! You should change the size of you buffer ie `hex` it must be at least 3 bytes. You use BYTE for both `buffer` and `hex` though so you can't use BYTE for `hex`.

Comment: So, let's assume, that I'd like to read 4 chars from my binary file. To do that I create a table buffer[4] and I use fread(buffer, 1, 4, file1). Then I use sprintf(hex, "%02x", (unsigned int) buffer[i++]), where hex is an table with 9 elements. Do I understand it right?

Comment: The only thing you need to remember is the difference of an actual byte which is 1 byte in size obviously. And a string representation, where each character is 1 byte + a terminating `\0`.

Comment: Hi again, I've updated my source code in question. Unfortunately I still can't open copy test.pdf. Could you glimpse of what did i wrong this time?

Answer (score 1):

When you said you can't open your copy, you mean you have an error in `fopen("test.txt", "r")`? Did you check `errno` value? Check `perror()`  and `strerror()`.
Besides, you have no loop in second program.

Comment: No, I mean that I can't open test.pdf in my pdf viewer.

Comment: You are reading only 2 bytes from "text.txt" file into buffer and writing `size` bytes in "test.pdf". Read carefully foo answer and use a loop for reading bytes from test.txt and write test.pdf until the end of "test.txt": see `man fscanf` and study it.